# R - editing of headers (contains values, which I need to separate and plot)

Tags: r

I am a beginner with R and having some problems. My header is containing values, which I would like to plot. I tried to build a matrix, but since it is a very big dataset, I thought there might be a easier solution. Here is one example how one dataset looks like:

`em310/ex270_raw

19.40`

I would like to have the em-values (only the value 310) as a row and the ex-values (only the value 270) as columns. Further I know how to plot them. I only would like to separate the header into its values for building a matrix with these values.

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried already?

Comment: No not really. I only played around with the functions "paste" and "substr".

Answer (score 1):

> `data<-c("em50/ex40","em120/ex980")`
>   `vect<-strsplit(data,"/")seperate em and ex values`
>   `vect[[i]][2]#give you the ex values`
>   `vect[[i]][1] #give you the em values`
>   so :
>   `values<-matrix(rep(0,nrow(data)^2),nrow(data),nrow(data))`
>   `for(i in 1:length(data){`
>   `values[i,]<-c(gsub("em","",vect[[i]][1]),gsub("ex","",vect[[i]][2]))`
>   `}`

Can you be more explicit ?

All your data are in this format ? emvalue/exvalue_raw 19.40

If this is the cas you have to :

First : split emvalue and exvalue bye the pattern "/"
Then : replace em by nothing to have only the value.

```
gsub("em","","em310")
```

Do the same thing for exvalue.

```
gsub("ex","","ex270")
```

you will have to caractere vector with your values.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes all my data is in this format. In the header I have like 500 different emvalues/exvalues_raw (header) and below this I get for every emvalue/exvalue_raw  a response-value (rows). Is there any other code which I can use beside the one you posted, because with the one you showed here I need to tell R explicit each value of em and ex (but I have like 500 of these). Thx

Comment: I think you didn't know our friend Google...
If their em and ex do the same length try with the function `substr`

For example `substr("abcdef", 2 ,5)` will give you "cdef".

Comment: I tied this function, but maybe I was adding something wrong. Thanks! But how do I separate the values from each other so that I get a matrix with em-values as a column and ex-values as a row, with their specific outcome-responses?

Comment: I think you have to learn the basis with R, your problem is quite simple to solve, but you dont show us your data. It's difficult to help you.

Trie to manipulate some caracter on R with quite simple example to help you understand how it works.

Comment: Your data are like : `emvalue/exvalue`

For example : `em120/ex150` or like `105-120/20-150` where em and ex have values different for each rows ?

Comment: They look like the first one you mentioned em120/ex150.

Comment: So why the answer i give you yesterday didn't work ?

It's exactly the solution.